# Wordpress order custom post type

Tags: wordpress, search, posts

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I'm new to php so it is very much learning on the job.

I am customising an existing Wordpress theme but I am facing a problem with the themes advanced search/results.

The theme has no way to order search results and I know that the default order for Wordpress is by date. Currently if I perform a search, the results are displayed in date order but I need the results to be price high to low.

The current code is as follows

```
<?php /* If there are no posts to display, such as an empty archive page */ ?>
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
        <h1 class="posttitle"><?php _e( 'Not Found', THE_LANG ); ?></h1>
        <div class="entry">
            <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested property archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', THE_LANG ); ?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="nvr-prop-container row">
<?php if( have_posts() ){ ?>
    <div class="search-title twelve columns">
        <h4><?php _e('Search Result', THE_LANG); ?> (<?php echo $wp_query->post_count; ?>)</h4>
    </div>

    <?php
    $nvr_idnum = 0;
    $nvr_typecol = "nvr-prop-col";
    $nvr_imgsize = "property-image";
    ?>
    <ul id="nvr-prop-search" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $nvr_typecol ); ?>">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            $nvr_idnum++;

            echo nvr_prop_get_box( $nvr_imgsize, get_the_ID(), 'element columns', $nvr_unit, $nvr_cursymbol, $nvr_curplace );


            $nvr_classpf=""; 

    endwhile; // End the loop. Whew.
    ?>
```

I then decided to try and sort the results so I created

```
$sort_properties = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'properties',
    'meta_key'          => $nvr_initial.'_price',
    'meta_value'        => $nvr_price,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
));

<?php /* If there are no posts to display, such as an empty archive page */ ?>
    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
        <article id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
            <h1 class="posttitle"><?php _e( 'Not Found', THE_LANG ); ?></h1>
            <div class="entry">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested property archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', THE_LANG ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </article>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="nvr-prop-container row">
    <?php if( $sort_properties->have_posts() ){ ?>
        <div class="search-title twelve columns">
            <h4><?php _e('Search Result', THE_LANG); ?> (<?php echo $wp_query->post_count; ?>)</h4>
        </div>

        <?php
        $nvr_idnum = 0;
        $nvr_typecol = "nvr-prop-col";
        $nvr_imgsize = "property-image";
        ?>
        <ul id="nvr-prop-search" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $nvr_typecol ); ?>">

        <?php
        while ( $sort_properties->have_posts() ) : $sort_properties->the_post(); 
                $nvr_idnum++;

                echo nvr_prop_get_box( $nvr_imgsize, get_the_ID(), 'element columns', $nvr_unit, $nvr_cursymbol, $nvr_curplace );


                $nvr_classpf=""; 

        endwhile; // End the loop. Whew.
        ?>
```

Now when I perform a search, the posts are sorted based on price which is fantastic but... now regardless of how I search all of the site posts are now being displayed.

I felt I was so close to finding a solution but I would very much grateful if someone cold advise me with this.

Kind regards

S

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the [Search Parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) and probably use the new meta_query structure:

```
$search_query = get_search_query();
$sort_properties = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'properties',
    's'                 => $search_query,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'          => $nvr_initial.'_price',
        'value'        => $nvr_price,
    )
));
```

I remember having some trouble, not using "meta_query" => array() for multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't do anything to the results.

Comment: edited my answer and added the meta_query => array() part.

Comment: Hello, thank you but i'm afraid it's not affected the results. <?php echo $wp_query->post_count; ?> displays the correct number of posts but the actual posts displayed remains the same.

Comment: i clicked a bit here: [WP_Query generator](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/) and updated my answer above. (removed meta_ prefix from key/value)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order only by the 'meta_val_num' without the 'date' like:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'price',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Code from: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters